# Get Stream basing on WebViewBrush in Windows 8 Metro App

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, brush

Using `WebViewBrush` I can render web page content (it's screen shot) to e.g. `Rectangle` element. How to convert that screen shot (brush) into `Stream` so I can save it on disk or send over network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is not supported yet: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/no/winappswithcsharp/thread/dd66c749-efed-4b55-a716-e0aa3a637d28

Comment: Megan, But Evernote's 'Skitch' is providing capture facility (from maps) in their windows store app it seems....

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it'll work but maybe you can try WriteableBitmapEx: http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/ ?

Comment: Nope, neither WPF's `RenderTargetBitmap` nor `WriteableBitmap.Render` are supported...